# I have accidendently removed android.widget.button from intellisense window in android studio how to get it back?

Tags: android

While coding I have accidentally removed the Android.widget.Button class from the intellisense window. now I don't receive any hint in window when I type the class name Button in java class. how to get it back in Android Studio?

screenshot, no reference to Button class available

[image]

Comment: Choose File > Invalidate Caches / Restart. It must be caching problem, I don't think you can modify or even remove that file.

Comment: I tried this option but noting happened, still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in android studio go to

**File / Settings / Editor / General/ Auto import**

[image]

and under java title should be box with this title **"Exculde form import and completion"**
remove your components from there and click on ok and it should be ok now !